# Extend the length of a cone

Tags: extrude, scale

[image]

I am having trouble extending this cone outwards, ie to the left. I have set the pivot point to 3D cursor and the Orientation in the active tool section to Normal, pressed s to scale and then z, then z again to get the axis following the angle of the face but the scaling does not seem to work properly. By not work properly I mean that the radius of the open end of the elongated cone is the same diameter is in the picture above not bigger as it should be, giving me essentially a cylinder on the end of a cone as you can see by the length of the edges in the following pic compared to the length of the edge at the head of the cork.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas as to how I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

[image]

It's the loop selected, and  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, Edge slide, with <kbd>Alt</kbd> held down, or  <kbd>C</kbd> pressed, to release the clamp.

Comment: @stphnl329's is more general, it will do scaling irrespective of the edge direction.

Comment: That's it exactly thanks Robin!!

Comment: Thanks Robin, I had no idea this is possible :).

Answer (score 5):

You've got the perfect setup for the cone from that cylinder.

Select all the vertices on the end you want to be a point, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to merge, and select *At Center* in the popup menu.

**Edit**

Ok, clarification from the comments:

To expand the outer rim, select the rim and press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Z</kbd> twice. This will scale the face only on the local XY axes and not cause it to protrude any further. If the local axes aren't lined up with the edges, select *Normal* under *Transformation Orientations* near the top of the screen. You may also need to fill in the face if it still isn't working.

[image: menu]

Comment: Ah... thanks for the response but you missed the point, pun intended :-) I think I must have badly phrased my question, sorry. The object is a champagne cork (I have not merged at center as the bottom face is not visble in render). The selected faces are too short, I need them to be longer, so they stretch further leftwards, making the hole further left, but also bigger. It is not very obvious from the image, but those faces if extended all the way right, would form a cone. But I need to extend/ stretch the other way.

Comment: Got it, edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer but I'm still not getting it to work. I think Robin has nailed it below... but thanks again for input.

Comment: @stphnl329 Thank you for contributing! Even an answer which misunderstood the question may be helpful for users who also misunderstood the question and are searching for a solution. But once you post a q/a, you surrender knowledge to the community; *please* don't make it personal with comments about your feelings (heart/soul). It exacerbates giving feedback or voting.

Comment: lol it was a lighthearted pun in response to Mark's pun :-) I'll remove the pun, seeing the potential for misunderstanding

Comment: @stphnl329 Oh man, I loved that pun. Keep 'em coming :).