# How to add similar slant vertices with same angle?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make slant vertices similar to the other vertices extruded. I want it at the same angle. What would be the approach to handling things like these?

I want the orange marked area to be replicated in the yellow region and close this circuit.

[image]

[image]

This is the type C cut out. Basically an oval shape.
[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162692/35559) what you mean?

Comment: No, I want to build the outer ring which is at 36 degree angle from the inner ring.  The idea is to make it a continuing slant slope. I tried extruding a vertice from the inner ring ( you can see in the image ) but that is not aligned and is on a different angle than the top ring vertice angle.

I have updated the post. Please check.

Comment: Thanks.. is the middle tube a circular?

Comment: No, it's an oval shape. It's a cut out of USB-C type charger cable. I have mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two rings of vertices are aligned along one of the world axis (in my example the Z axis):

Select all faces between the two circles and press Alt J (Tris to quads).
Activate vertex snapping.
Select the lower circle, Press E, Z and hover the mouse on one of the upper circle's vertex; click to confirm.

[image]

Press S, B, click on vertex A, click on vertex B.

On wireframe mode, select all the area and press M > Merge by distance, then Shift N (Recalculate normals).

Works only on 4.0 version and above.

If the two circles are not aligned along an axis, choose or create a face that is aligned along their alignement and press the plus icon on the Transform orientations menu, then use the same method choosing the needed Axis.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh for the help :)